# Is the verb "grep" too geeky for E&R?

Tags: discussion

## grep

1. To gather information related to a particular subject from a large amount of data.
2. To ascertain the meaning or function of an explanation.

> [I can't grep reliable guidelines by which to narrow design options.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/what-are-programmable-logic-ics-of-different-complexity-used-for)

Is the verb "grep" too geeky for E&R?

Comment: Is anything too geeky for E&R?

Comment: I thought people at E&R were also geeks. Is the word geek only for CS majors?

Comment: @Rick_2047, Certainly E&R users are geeks; but to what extent? ;)

Comment: That's not the exact meaning I've seen used for grep.  I've only seen it used to mean "locate a piece of information within a huge pile of information" rather than a general "gather information" sense.  See also "man 1 grep"

Comment: ...and here i was thinking it was just the name of a unix command line utility... can I awk you something? what did you sed the other day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Most EE's that have been out of school for 10 years or more don't know it.

Comment: Though there may be many EE's frequenting E&R, I doubt they are the majority. The *Hacker/Maker* crowd must be larger. Anyway, I certainly didn't learn about *grep* at school.

Comment: I think that the qualifier is not 'time since school' but 'time since using an OS other than Windows'.